# rails webpacker+bootstrap popover show not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

```
#html.slim
= link_to 'Tasks', '#', data: {content: ("And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"), placement: "bottom", toggle: "popover", trigger: "click", template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header">Driver Compliance Management <span class="badge badge-success">Advanced</span></h3><div class=popover-body><p><small>Easily keep your drivers current and compliant</small></p><ul><li>Build a driver’s DQ file without any extra work</li><li>Avoid expirations with automated notifications</li><li>Access records from any device</li></ul></div><div class="popover-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block ">Start Free Trial</button></div></div>' }
```

javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

This code works correctly without the webpacker, but when I tried use it with webpack, it does not show correctly.

With webpack I can only show " And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" It's content, but i tried to delete this content, moved to js, nothing worked.

Screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ul75ERpFJ6gQnQV43uEkyAR64yN_4WV9

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You should add code or images directly to your post, since web-addresses can change and it makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thx very much for corrected my post :)